# Using PostGIS raster in GeoServer. Is it necessary?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geotiff-tiff

What is the reason to convert GeoTIFF (or other Geo-Dataset) to PostGIS raster and store them in GeoServer?

If it's for using the PostGIS functions, what is the problem of storing the original GeoTIFF data directly by GeoServer, and processing them by some (let's say) python scripts?

Comment: I've rarely found any benefits to storing rasters in postgis.

Answer (score 7):

The typical reason to store raster in the database is to leverage the database as an analytical engine, one can do pretty powerful queries that would compare, join, and summarize data from different rasters and vector layers.

For pure data serving, I'm not aware of specific benefits, which is also why the GeoServer imagemosaic-jdbc module fell unmaintained and was eventually removed.

Comment: So the database cannot be an analytical engine, if it's based on the original GeoTIFF data?

Comment: When the raster data is stored as GeoTIFF the database does not have access to it, because the files are located outside. In my experience adding Raster directly to the database only makes sense when you do many operations that combine raster and vector data. It you only want to display GeoTIFFs in the web, there is no need to convert them to PostGIS raster.

Comment: PostGIS can access data from TIFF files https://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html#outdb. That gives worse performance than storing rasters into the database but the benefit is exactly that you do not need to store the rasters into the database.